# Assign new Record Types on Managed Package object on upgrade?

Tags: managed-package, profile, record-type, postinstall

We have an object in a managed package, that in previous versions had no record types. In the next version, it  has two. On install of test versions of the package, all profiles are assigned Master only. Can we assign both record types to all profiles that have Create on the object, either with metadata in the packaging org, or a post-install script?

Comment: @sfdcfox - Hey, any thought about this question?